# Python script to search directory for certain file type then append their contents together

Tags: python-3.x, file, addition

I am trying to make a python script that will search a directory for all files that end with a specific file extension called .math (basically a text file with numbers inside of them).

How would I approach doing so?

Imagine I have files hello.math, hello2.math, and goodbye.math

Lets say hello.math has 10, hello2.math has 3 and goodbye.math has 0.

i would want the script to search for all of  the .math files in the current directory then sum them up.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code (or errors you have encountered) so we can help you

Comment: @Antoine I haven't tried anything yet. I just wanted to find the best approach to this before I attempt it as I am not exactly sure how to do it.

Comment: I would do the following steps :
1-Explore recursively all the name files contained in the directory
2-Check for the right extension
3-Open and parse content if the extension is the wanted one 
4-Increment a variable with the read number in your main program?

Comment: @Antoine Okay thank you, I will try to follow that procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So not sure if you want to recursively search through a directory structure, or just list files in one directory.  This should get you going.

```
import os

MATH_FILES = list()

def single_dir(name)
    global MATH_FILES
    names = [os.path.join(name, item) for item in os.listdir(name)]
        for name in names:
           if ".math" in name and os.path.isfile(name):
               print("%s has .math in the name" % name)
               MATH_FILES.append(name)

def recursive(name):
    global MATH_FILES
    if ".math" in name and os.path.isfile(name):
        print("%s has .math in the name" % name)
        MATH_FILES.append(name)
    try:
        names = [os.path.join(name, item) for item in os.listdir(name)]
        for name in names:
            recurse(name)
    except:
        # Can't listdir() a file, so we expect this to except at the end of the tree.  
        pass

def sum_file_contents():
    value = int()
    for file in MATH_FILES:
        value += int(open(file, "r").read().strip())
    return value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Choose implemntation here
    # recursive("<insert base path here>")
    # single_dir("<insert base path here>")
    print(sum_file_contents())
```

So some things.... Firstly in the if name conditional you need to choose either the single_dir or recursive function, and specify a path entry point (like /dir or C:\dir or whatever).  The sum_file_contents will fail if there is anything other than an int in the file.  Though your example states that is what you're looking for.

In conclusion, it would be good if you gave it a try before asking the question. I think the community at large isn't here to write code for you, but to help you if you get stuck.  This is a super simple problem.  if you google find files in a directory I bet there are literally dozens of answers, and that would at least give you a base of a code example. You could then say I can find my .math files like this, how do I sum them?  You could probably find that answer simply as well. Please note I'm not trying to be rude with this paragraph.

Note: I did not test this code

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't exactly asking people to write the code for me. I was asking on how to do it, sort of what steps to take. Either way thank you for your assistance.

Comment: NP :) Like I said I'm not trying to be rude or give you a hard time,  but you'll get some flak for asking questions like this some times.  If you come in with a more specific problem and talk about your thoughts on the matter, you'll typically get more traction and faster answers.