# Followup for searching directory for a specific file extension and performing a sum to add their contents together

Tags: python-3.x, file, sum

This is a follow up to my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661506/python-script-to-search-directory-for-certain-file-type-then-append-their-conten/51662174?noredirect=1#comment90288199_51662174). Essentially the idea is to add up the contents of all files that end with .math in the /home/pi/math. directory. Currently I have 3 files: test.math, hello.math, hi.math - all of them have at least 1.00. The issue is that 1. It doesn't seem to read the contents of the files properly and it isn't adding them up.

The idea is that it would add those 3 files (eventually I want to add them up into one variable) and display the total. Please note that I do want to include floats.

```
import os

srcdir = "/home/pi/math/"
files = os.listdir(srcdir)


def sum_file_contents():
    value = float()
    for file in srcdir:
      if file.endswith(('math')):
          value += float(open(file, "r").read().strip())
      return value

for file in files:
    if file.endswith(('math')):
       print(file)
       print(sum_file_contents())
```

Output

```
test.math
0.0
hello.math
0.0
hi.math
0.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main `for` loop iterates through `files`, which comes from `os.listdir(srcdir)`, but then your `sum_file_contents()` tries to do the same thing again, except it iterates through the `srcdir` as a string, which naturally doesn't give you the directory listing. The main `for` loop is redundant and you should simply fix `sum_file_contents()` by calling `os.listdir()` while iterating over it:

```
import os

srcdir = "/home/pi/math/"

def sum_file_contents():
    value = float()
    for file in os.listdir(srcdir):
      if file.endswith(('math')):
          value += float(open(os.path.join(srcdir, file), "r").read().strip())
    return value
print(sum_file_contents())
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. You are right that it is redundant. When I try this version of the script I get the following error `code "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sumbalance.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(sum_file_contents())
  File "sumbalance.py", line 9, in sum_file_contents
    value += float(open(file, "r").read().strip())
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.math'"  code` Unfortunately I don't really know why this is happening, especially for test.math.

Comment: I see. This is because `os.listdir()` returns only the file names without path names, and you have to use `os.path.join()` to prepend your `srcdir` to the file names. I've updated my answer with the correction then.

Comment: Okay thank you for informing me, I didn't know that. The script now runs, but it only shows the contents of one file instead of all files. In this case it displays 1.25 which is the amount for test.math. Is this because it isn't properly looping through all of the files?

Comment: I see. I did not notice that you had improperly indented `return value` inside the `for` loop, so the function immediately returns at the end of the first iteration. Simply move the `return` statement outside the loop and it would work. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Ah thank you. Sorry for all of the questions, just trying my best to learn and simple things like that keep getting me.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
srcdir = "/home/pi/math/"
files = os.listdir(srcdir)

def sum_file_contents(file):
    value = 0.0
    f = open(file,'r')
    for line in f:
        value += float(line.strip())
    return value

total_value = 0.0
for file in files:
    if file.endswith(('math')):
        print(file)
        print(sum_file_contents(file))
        total_value += sum_file_contents(file)
print(total_value)
```

This will handle even if there are more lines with floats in files.

Comment: Thank you for your input, this is great. I appreciate you teaching me a different way to do this.